# Angular 9 HTTP Interceptor doesn't work when using @ngrx/store

Tags: angular, state, ngrx, angular-http-interceptors

I'm new to Angular, right now I'm learning NgRx to manage my application state.

When I try to implements the reducer to my HttpInterceptor, it doesn't work anymore. the intercept function can't get the state from my reducer every time I try to using login function.
Here's my code:

```
//app.module.ts
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared.module';
import { CoreModule } from './core.module';
import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';
import * as fromApp from './store/app.reducer'

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, HeaderComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    SharedModule,
    CoreModule,
    StoreModule.forRoot(fromApp.appReducer)
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

app.reducer.ts

```
import * as fromAuth from '../auth/store/auth.reducer';
import { ActionReducerMap } from '@ngrx/store';


export interface AppState {
    shoppingList: fromShoppingList.State;
    auth: fromAuth.State
}

export const appReducer: ActionReducerMap<AppState> = {
    shoppingList: fromShoppingList.shoppingListReducer,
    auth: fromAuth.authReducer
}
```

auth.reducer.ts

```
import { User } from '../user.model';
import * as AuthActions from './auth.action';


export interface State {
    user: User;
}

const inititalState: State = {
    user: null
}

export function authReducer(state, action: AuthActions.AuthActions) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case AuthActions.LOGIN:
            const user = new User(
                action.payload.email, 
                action.payload.userId, 
                action.payload.token, 
                action.payload.exparitionDate
            );
            return {
                ...state,
                user: user
            }
        case AuthActions.LOGOUT:
            return {
                ...state,
                user: null
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

auth.action.ts

```
import { Action } from '@ngrx/store';

export const LOGIN = 'LOGIN';
export const LOGOUT = 'LOGOUT';

export class Login implements Action {
    readonly type = LOGIN;

    constructor(public payload: {email: string, userId: string, token: string, exparitionDate: Date}) {}
}

export class Logout implements Action {
    readonly type = LOGOUT;
}

export type AuthActions = Login | Logout
```

auth-interceptor.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpInterceptor,
  HttpRequest,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpParams
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { take, exhaustMap, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import * as fromApp from '../store/app.reducer';

@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    private store: Store<fromApp.AppState>) {}

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
    return this.store.select('auth').pipe(
      take(1),
      map(authState => {
        console.log(authState); //this is undefined when i log it
        return authState.user;
      }),
      exhaustMap(user => {
        if (!user) {
          return next.handle(req);
        }
        const modifiedReq = req.clone({
          params: new HttpParams().set('auth', user.token)
        });
        return next.handle(modifiedReq);
      })
    );
  }
}
```

my login function:

```
login(email: string, password: string) {
    return this.http
      .post<AuthResponseData>(
        'https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyPassword?key=' + environment.firebaseAPIKey,
        {
          email: email,
          password: password,
          returnSecureToken: true
        }
      )
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError),
        tap(resData => {
          console.log('hello');
          this.handleAuthentication(
            resData.email,
            resData.localId,
            resData.idToken,
            +resData.expiresIn
          );
        })
      );
  }
```

edit:
this is my core.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';

import { ShoppingListService } from './shopping-list/shopping-list.service';
import { RecipeService } from './recipes/recipe.service';
import { AuthInterceptorService } from './auth/auth-interceptor.service';

@NgModule({
  providers: [
    ShoppingListService,
    RecipeService,
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: AuthInterceptorService,
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class CoreModule {}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing setting the intial state `state = inititalState`

```
export function authReducer(state = inititalState, action: AuthActions.AuthActions) {
.....
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ar54qn

Comment: If you can create stackblitz link to reproduce your problem It'll be easy to help you.

Comment: okay, I will send you my stackblitz link. Please give me a second

Comment: I tried to up my source to stackblitz but it got error when running. Can you help me check this?
This is my stackblitz link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zkyqde

Comment: Check the edit comment and the updated link , I already fixed it! 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ar54qn

Comment: Thank you,  @wessam yaacob
Can you tell me what's wrong with my code? why it get error when I using http interceptor?

Comment: Which error exactly you have ? I see the stackblitz link is working and the only error I'm getting is Unauthorize which is normal because we are not using real data

Comment: I don't get error when log in while using stackblitz but it got error when i using localhost. The error is: in TypeError: Cannot read property 'user' of undefined
    at MapSubscriber.project (header.component.ts:28)
when I checked the Interceptor, the state in there is undefined.

Comment: So it works well in stackblitz but throwing exception in your localhost env ?

Comment: You have to check your login result, may be someting happen I can't catch in my side because I don't have the right access to your login service and I just hardcoded the login result

Comment: the prop authState.user of function ngOnInit() in header.component.ts said it undefined, so it always throw exception everytime I run the code. The result is same when I try to log this prop in my interceptor. So I think the problem here is my authState doesn't work correctly in my localhost env, but I don't know where to fix it...

Comment: try to download the working code from the link in my answer, there is option in stackblitz to download the full sample , run it , if it works correctly so you can compare the code if not let me know we can find another way to fix it